# How to Color ListBox Items?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to change the color of a `ListBox`  items. The code I have doesn't seem to work.
It just adds the namespace of the class to the `ListBox` items.

```
class myListboxItem
{
    public Color ItemColor { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public myListboxItem(Color c, string m)
    {
        ItemColor = c;
        Message = m;
    }
}
```

The code to add the item to the `ListBox`:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new myListboxItem(Color.Red,"SKIPPED: " + partThreeOfPath));
```

This adds a item to the `ListBox`, in black `AddFoldersToClientFolder.myListboxItem`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DrawItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of ListBox:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (myListboxItem)listBox1.Items[e.Index];
    e.DrawBackground();

    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(item.ItemColor))
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Message, listBox1.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
}
```

Note: you also need to set [`DrawMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of ListBox to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` or `DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable`

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm getting an error saying the index is not valid? Also I don't understand how to apply this on a specific item instead of all the listbox items?